# PLSQL IMPLICIT CURSOR No Data Found After CURSOR

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor, implicit

I have a Main cursor that is working fine.

```
declare

    v_firm_id number;
    amount number;
    v_total_sum TABLE_TEMP.TOTAL_SUM%TYPE;

    CURSOR MT_CURSOR IS
        SELECT firm_id FROM t_firm;

BEGIN
    OPEN MT_CURSOR;
    LOOP
        FETCH MT_CURSOR INTO v_firm_id;
        EXIT WHEN MT_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(sysdate, 'mi:ss')  ||'--- '|| v_firm_id)
        INSERT INTO TABLE_TEMP(TOTAL_SUM) VALUES(v_firm_id) 
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(20);

    BEGIN
        FOR loop_emp IN
            (SELECT TOTAL_SUM INTO v_total_sum FROM TABLE_TEMP)
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(to_char(sysdate, 'mi:ss')  ||'--- '|| v_total_sum || '-TEST--');
        END LOOP loop_emp;
    END;
end;
```

Everything Works fine except `dbms_output.put_line(v_total_sum || '---');`

I do not get any data there. I get the correct number of rows. which it inserted.

Comment: Is TABLE_TEMP a Global Temporary Table? If so, what is its retention setting?

Comment: Standard question - is `dbms_output` enabled? Can you run it through the debugger and see what it's doing? Also, the question title says "No Data Found" - how is that related to the `dbms_output` question? Is data present in the table at the end or not?

Comment: @APC `TABLE_TEMP` is an actual table which I already created before running this procedure.

Comment: Well, what is its retention setting?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes it is enabled becuase I have tested it in this same code by doing ` DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(sysdate, 'mi:ss')  ||'--- '|| v_firm_id)`

Comment: Do you see any message or see something with wrong value for `v_total_sum`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I just edited the `DBMS_OUTPUT`. Only thing I get in out is the Systime` and Null for `v_total_sum`. I get the correct number of rows. which is two. I know that because I am expecting two rows.

Comment: Not that it matters now, but there are two retention options for global temporary tables, `on commit delete rows` and `on commit preserve rows`. We were asking which one you used in your code above because if it was `on commit delete rows` that might have explained why there were no rows in it after you committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the cursor FOR loop has a redundant `into` clause which it appears the compiler silently ignores, and so `v_total_sum` is never used.

Try this:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select firm_id from t_firm
    )
    loop
        insert into table_temp (total_sum) values (r.firm_id);
    end loop;

    dbms_lock.sleep(20);

    for r in (
        select total_sum from table_temp
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.total_sum || '---');
    end loop;

    commit;
end;
```

If this had been a stored procedure rather than an anonymous block and you had PL/SQL compiler warnings enabled with `alter session set plsql_warnings = 'ENABLE:ALL';` (or the equivalent preference setting in your IDE) then you would have seen:

```
PLW-05016: INTO clause should not be specified here
```

I also moved the `commit` to the end so you only commit once.

To summarise the comments below, the Cursor FOR loop construction declares, opens, fetches and closes the cursor for you, and is potentially faster because it fetches in batches of 100 (or similar - I haven't tested in recent versions). Simpler code has less chance of bugs and is easier to maintain in the future, for example if you need to add a column to the cursor.

Note the original version had:

```
for loop_emp in (...)
loop
    ...
end loop loop_emp;
```

This is misleading because `loop_emp` is the name of the **record**, not the cursor or the loop. The compiler is ignoring the text after `end loop` although really it should at least warn you. If you wanted to name the loop, you would use a [label like `<<LOOP_EMP>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#GUID-4CD12F11-2DB8-4B0D-9E04-DF983DCF9358) above it. (I always name my loop records `r`, similar to the `i` you often see used in numeric loops.)

Comment: so I do not need `CURSOR`?

Comment: You don't need to declare it explicitly when you can use a Cursor FOR loop construction. This declares, opens, fetches and closes the cursor for you.

Comment: William, I used your code to modify my code. I used `loop_emp.total_sum` and it started working. I got the output I was expecting. Do you see any reason why not use that? it would be lots of work to change my entire code. I only posted very small part of my entire code.

Comment: @user206168 - consistency is a virtue in code. When you use an explicit cursor for one loop and an implicit cursor for the second then your colleagues will wonder why. Sure, your code will work by just removing the `INTO v_total_sum` from the second cursor loop. But your is harder to understand than it needs to be.

Comment: Simpler is better - less chance of bugs and easier to maintain in the future. Also Cursor FOR loops automatically fetch in batches of 100 and so could be more efficient for a large number of rows (although in that case you probably wouldn't use a loop anyway).